# Как писать прилагательное, образованное от имени, которое пишется через дефис, в названии района?

Tags: прописная

Полный академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2006) указывает, что составные части арабских, тюркских, персидских и т. п. имен, обозначающие социальное положение, родственные отношения и т. п., а также служебные слова – такие, как ага, ад, аль, аш, бей, бек, заде, зуль, кызы, оглы, паша и др., пишутся, как правило, со строчной буквы и присоединяются к имени дефисом. В соответствии с этим правилом "Грамота" пишет, что следует писать: Бухар-жырау, проспект Бухар-жырау.

Как писать название района, образованное от этого имени?

Бухар-Жырауский район, Бухар-жырауский район или Бухаржырауский район?

И на какое правило при этом ссылаться?

Comment: Серж, спасибо, но это не опечатка: в тюркских языках слог "жи" произносится тверже, чем в русском - там слышится явное "жЫ" и пишем ЖЫ. В армянских пишем Я после Ч.

Comment: § 129. Следующие разряды прилагательных пишутся через дефис.
... сухово-кобылинский (Сухово-Кобылин). Исключения: москворецкий (от Москва-река), Китайгородский (от Китай-город).

Может быть, из-за того, что в _Бухар-жырау_ _жырау_ пишется с прописной, нужно, как, скажем, если бы был Москворецкий район, то Бухаржырауский писать слитно?

Исключения всего два? Или к исключениям относятся все те прилагательные в географических названиях, которые образованы от слов, пишущихся после дефиса со строчной, как в _москворецкий?

Answer (score 3):

В составных географических названиях сложные прилагательные пишутся слитно либо через дефис по правилам § 129 и 130 ***(при написании через дефис обе части таких прилагательных пишутся с прописной буквы).*** Ср.: Малоазиатское нагорье, Старооскольский район, Великоустюгский район, Василеостровский район, Среднедунайская равнина, Нижнерейнская низменность, Ближневосточный регион и Юго-Восточная Азия.

§ 129. Следующие разряды прилагательных пишутся через дефис.

1. Прилагательные, образованные от существительных, пишущихся через дефис, 
     прилагательные, образованные от пишущихся через дефис собственных имен, напр.: санкт-петербургский (от Санкт-Петербург), нью-йоркский (Нью-Йорк), аддис-абебский (Аддис-Абеба), коста-риканский (Коста-Рика).

> Основываясь на этом правиле, следует писать:   Бухар-Ж**и**рауский район. Обратите на опечатку в этом слове: вместе ***Ы*** пишется ***и.***

См.: Полный академический справочник. [Географические названия](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=69#pp69)

Comment: Серж, на имена собственные правило «ЖИ-ШИ пиши с буквой И» не распространяется. Встречаются названия и с "жы":

Жылыойский р-н, Кажым, ПорБажын, Ыджыдпарма...


А назван Бухар-Жырауский район так, скорее всего, в честь этого поэта 

--

 http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/72007/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80

Comment: Слава, именно на академике я увидел вариант с и. [Бухар-Жирауский район.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/825889/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80)

Comment: Для передачи иноязычных собственных имён используется т.н. практическая транскрипция, своя для каждого исходного языка. При этом в интересах однозначности обратного перевода допускаются необычные для конечного языка буквенные сочетания.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Практическая_транскрипция